# Custom keyboard layout not used verbatim

Tags: x11, xkb

I've created a custom keyboard layout, `~/dot/c98.xkb`. It looks like this:

```
// vim: ft=xkb
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes "k" { include "evdev(evdev)" };
    xkb_geometry "g" { include "pc(pc105)" };

    xkb_types "t" {
    };
    xkb_compat "c" {
    };
    xkb_symbols "s" {
    };
};
```

Obviously, there is actually stuff in the empty blocks, but I skipped it to save space.

Compiling and decompiling it through `xkbcomp c98.xkb c98.xkm; xkbcomp c98.xkm c98_xkm.xkb` creates a file that is equivalent to the original (as similar as any decompiled code is).

However, doing it through `xkbcomp c98.xkb $DISPLAY; xkbcomp $DISPLAY c98_display.xkb` results in an error message (it still works, though; message copied below), and a file that has some slight resemblance to the original:

- `keycodes` includes `evdev+aliases(qwerty)` instead of just `evdev`. It's been renamed to `evdev+aliases(qwerty)`.
- `types` contains a lot of stuff, but not what I specified (it seems to just include `complete`), and has been renamed to `complete`/
- `compat` contains what I told it to, but with more `virtual_modifiers`. That one is also named `complete`.
- `symbols` contains what it should, except the `name[group1]` field has been changed to `English (US)`, and some of the `type` fields have weird values - I guess it stores indices and not names, and since the `types` field is corrupted... This block's name has been changed to `pc+us+inet(evdev)`.
- `geometry` seems to contain exactly what it should, including the block name.

It seems like `xkbcomp` only copies some of the blocks for some reason, leaving the `keycodes` and `types` fields alone.

---

The aforementioned error message when trying to set the layout is:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAtom (invalid Atom parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  135 (XKEYBOARD)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (XkbSetNames)
  Atom id in failed request:  0x435345
  Serial number of failed request:  70
  Current serial number in output stream:  73
```

---

The full source code, as well as a diff between `c98_xkm.xkb` and `c98_display.xkb` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Caagr98/92c256885cdf22f30fa7d2a907cdf3dd).